# How to wait for the last function to complete

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I'm working on a program to sort all my image files into folders by year and then by month.
I've written a series of functions that, when run individually, will complete the task.

My problem is, if i run these functions straight after each other, it wont work. It simply looks like the rearranging of files on my os is happening so slowly, that my program will outrun it and cause 'No such file or directory' errors because some folders hasn't been created yet.

**How can i make my program wait for the last function and continue when it is completed?**

I thought of simply sleep()ing it off, but that feels like a half solution since the time could vary based on the size of my data set.

```
import time
import os
import shutil
from os.path import join

#path = "C:/Users/caspe/Desktop/Iphone Sync/jpg"
path = "C:/Users/caspe/Desktop/TEST"
list_ = os.listdir(path)
increment = 0

database = {}

"""Create a database of all the files, to be able to work around duplicate dates."""
def create_db():
    new_database = {}
    for file_ in list_:
        path_to_file = join(path, file_)
        t = os.path.getmtime(path_to_file)
        t_str = time.ctime(t)
        t_obj = time.strptime(t_str)
        form_t = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M", t_obj)
        form_t = form_t.replace(":", "꞉")
        #print (form_t)
        #print (t)
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_)
        ext = ext[1:]
    
        if ext == '':
            continue
        else:
            if form_t in new_database:
                new_database[form_t] += 1
            else:
                new_database[form_t] = 0

    #print(new_database)
    return new_database

"""Do a simple reset of all filenames equal to the number of an incrementing integer."""
def reset_names():
    i = 0
    for file_ in list_:
        path_to_file = join(path, file_)
        os.rename(path + "/" + file_, os.path.split(path_to_file)[0] + "/" + str(i) + os.path.splitext(path_to_file)[1])
        i += 1

"""Rename all files based on date."""
def rename_files():
    for file_ in list_:
        path_to_file = join(path, file_)
        t = os.path.getmtime(path_to_file)
        t_str = time.ctime(t)
        t_obj = time.strptime(t_str)
        form_t = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M", t_obj)
        form_t = form_t.replace(":", "꞉")

        if database.keys().__contains__(form_t):
            new_name = os.path.split(path_to_file)[0] + '/' + form_t + "-" + str(database[form_t]) + os.path.splitext(path_to_file)[1]
            database[form_t] -= 1
            os.rename(path_to_file, new_name)
        else:
            print("no images found")
            #continue

"""Sort all files into folders based on year."""
def sort_files_by_year():
    year_folders = []

    # Sort all files into folders based on year
    for file_ in list_:
        #path_to_file = join(path, file_)
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_)
        month = name[3:5]
        year = name[6:10]
        ext = ext[1:]
        #print(month)
        #print(year)
        
        # folder 2021
        #   - folder for each month
        #       - all pics in correct "month" folder

        # We do not want folders, so skip it
        if ext == '':
            continue

        if os.path.exists(path + "/" + year):
            shutil.move(path + "/" + file_, path + "/" + year + "/" + file_)
        else:
            new_year_folder = os.makedirs(path + "/" + year)
            year_folders.append(new_year_folder)
            shutil.move(path + "/" + file_, path + "/" + year + "/" + file_)
    
"""Sort the contents of each "year" folder, into "month" folders."""
def sort_each_year_folder_by_month():
    # Loop through each "year" folder
    # Inside each "year" sort files based on month
    for folder in list_:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(folder)
        print (name)
        new_path = path + "/" + name
        new_list = os.listdir(new_path)

        # We only want folders
        if ext != '':
            continue

        for file_ in new_list:
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_)
            month = name[3:5]
            #ext = ext[1:]

            # We do not want folders, so skip it
            if ext == '':
                continue
            
            if os.path.exists(new_path + "/" + month):
                shutil.move(new_path + "/" + file_, new_path + "/" + month + "/" + file_)
            else:
                os.makedirs(new_path + "/" + month)
                shutil.move(new_path + "/" + file_, new_path + "/" + month + "/" + file_)

    

#

"""Step 1."""
#reset_names()

"""Step 2."""
#database = create_db()
#rename_files()

"""Step 3."""
#sort_files_by_year()
#sort_each_year_folder_by_month()
```

Comment: Could you put your code in the question to help beter understand the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: shutil.move is synchronous. It should only return after the operation has finished. 
I would double check if this is really the error. Try printing the directory after creation and also print its contents , then try to pinpoint which move exactly is causing the error